# Flutter web_socket_channel cannot send ByteBuffer

Tags: flutter, websocket, bytebuffer

My Flutter app uses a web socket to send the mp3 file to the server directly. I need to slice mp3 file to small [ByteBuffer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-typed_data/ByteBuffer-class.html). I use [web_socket_channel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel) but when I send ByteBuffer, the _channel **onDone** immediately and the server has not received data from the app.

```
  void sendData(ByteBuffer data) {
    _channel.sink.add(data);
  }


   listenToMessage() {
    if (_channel != null) {
      _channel.stream.listen(
        (message) {
          print("websocket listen: $message");
        },
        onDone: () {
          print("Websocket listen onDone");
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

I saw method [sendByteBuffer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/WebSocket/sendByteBuffer.html) in
[Websocket](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/WebSocket-class.html) in [dart:html](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/dart-html-library.html) lib, but cannot use in the mobile app.

Comment: i need send to server bytebuffer type, not Uint8list, Uint8list is a array